# Magento Admin Add/Edit Review -> removing Summary of Review Field required validation

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

How can i remove mandatory required for the Summary of Review Field in the Admin panel?

Answer (score 4):

copy

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

and change (line 125 or 131)

```
'required'  => true,
```

to

```
'required'  => false,
```

and refresh the cache!

Comment: Rewrite would be a bit more ideal.