# Magento How to remove the title field from product review form?

Tags: php, magento

how can I remove the the title text field from magento product review form?

It could be something as simple as making the title not required and hiding it thought css, is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean the Summary of Your Review field?  If not, maybe you can be more specific?

Comment: I need to make this change on the form where a user can make a new rating for a product, check this screnshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e61x4glc3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595149/magento-admin-add-edit-review-removing-summary-of-review-field-required-valid

Comment: That will make not required, you could use Jquery or CSS to remove the <li>

Comment: thanks for the help, but that solution seems to apply only to the backend and I need to remove it from frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide with CSS or disable required, like this:

copy

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

and change (line 125 or 131)

```
'required'  => true,
```

to

```
'required'  => false,
```

and refresh the cache!