# How to remove nickname and summary from review product?

Tags: php, magento2

I want to remove some fields from review products (summary and nickname). I found one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066741/how-can-i-remove-mandatory-required-for-the-review-fields-nickname-summary-of)

But I didn't see `/public_html/app/code/Magento` folder.

I use Magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you want to modify is placed in Magento_Review module - `vendor/magento/module-review`. You have to create a new module, i.e. Codeit_Review, set dependency to Magento_Review and adjust the product review functionality within it.